# Playa not rendering within a Stash List

Tags: playa, stash

The below code works just fine on it’s own, however as soon as I drop it into a stash list and call it later in my template no results are shown. Is this a parse issue?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="brand" entry_id="108"}
         {exp:playa:children field="brand-category"}
             <p>{count} - Category Name: {title} | Category URL: /products/brand/microsoft/{url_title}</p>
         {/exp:playa:children}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is how it looks when stashed up:

Call Embed and Display Data:

```
{!-- Set Stash List --}
 {stash:embed name="_common:_data/test-category-list" stash:id="108" process="inline" parse="inwards"}

{!-- Get Stash List --}
 {exp:stash:get_list name="related-category-list"}
 {brand-name}
 {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Embed File:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="related-category-list" parse_tags="yes"}

 {exp:channel:entries channel="brand" entry_id="{stash:id}"}
  {exp:playa:children field="brand-category" parse="inward"}
            {stash:brand-name}{title}{/stash:brand-name}
        {/exp:playa:children}
 {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it just needed to increase the depth of the list to "2" within the embed. Here is the code if anyone needs it.

Embed File:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="related-category-list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="brand" entry_id="{stash:id}"}
        {exp:playa:children field="brand-category"}
            {stash:category-name}{title}{/stash:category-name}
            {stash:category-url}{url_title}{/stash:category-url}
        {/exp:playa:children}
    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
```